# Getting inaccurate response.corr in Psychopy

Tags: python, psychopy

I use psychopy2 v1.85.2 for my experiment in Mac. I have gotten a message after an experiment as follows and then have some trouble in inaccurate response.corr though getting an accurate response.keys in excel. Please tell me how to get accurate response.corr.

```
FutureWarning:elementwise comparison failed;returning scalar                  
instead,but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
if (response0.keys == str(correctAns0) or (response0.keys == correctAns0):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response0.keys` will return a list, even if it contains just a single value. This is why it is named `.keys` rather than `.key`. e.g. if the subject pushed the `'a'` key, the results would be the single element list `['a']`.

You should treat it as a list and make comparisons like yours to a specified single item within that list. e.g.

```
# test against the zeroth list item rather than the entire list:
if response0.keys[0] == str(correctAns0): # etc
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. In fact, I make my experiment in builder without using code component and such an error is showed. Even if I write `if response0.keys[0] == str(correctAns0):` in code component, the error of List index out of range is represented. Please tell me how to get accurate response0.corr, if someone knows another way.

Comment: This site is really for programming questions. For Builder issues, you should take this to the forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org